# C++ passing struct by seemingly removes need to initialize

Tags: c++, struct

I'm reading the book "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup, and some of the code in chapter 2 has me confused. I've shortened the code from the book for the sake of this post.

The following code causes a compilation error "C4700 uninitialized local variable 'vector' used".

```
struct Vector
{
    int size;
    double* elements;
};

void vector_init(Vector vector, int size)
{
    vector.elements = new double[size];
    vector.size = size;
}

int main()
{
    Vector vector;
    vector_init(vector, 3);
}
```

Now this makes sense to me. What doesn't make sense to me, is that if I instead pass the Vector-struct as a reference, the error goes away.

```
struct Vector
{
    int size;
    double* elements;
};

void vector_init(Vector& vector, int size)
{
    vector.elements = new double[size];
    vector.size = size;
}

int main()
{
    Vector vector;
    vector_init(vector, 3);
}
```

Using this code as a starting point I've been able to populate the vector-struct and printed out its values. I fail to understand why passing it by reference means I now longer need to initialize the structure.

Comment: its warning, not an error

Comment: The second example (reference) does not attempt to read the uninitialized members of the struct.
The first example does a copy of the uninitialized vector. (using it)

Comment: Passing by value creates a copy: the copy is initialized, but the `vector` in main() is still not initialized. Passing by reference creates no copy, so the `vector` in main is correctly initialized. Using an `init` function like this looks like an anti-pattern. I'd use a constructor instead.

Comment: `vector_init` is totally useless without the reference, because it does not affect the original `vector` in `main` (only the copy which goes out of scope when the function returns).

Comment: A side note: In c++ `vector_init` should be a method of the struct (or replaced by a constructor).

Comment: Do you understand what references are, how they work, and how to use them? If so, then what, specifically don't you understand? This goes down to the fundamental principles of how references work. What does "now longer need to initialize" mean, since the shown code still initialized the `Vector`?

Comment: Seems you are confused about references. Using a reference does not mean that you no longer need to initialize anything. However it's perfectly legal to have a reference to uninitialized data, but it is not legal to copy uninitialized data. Using a reference prevents that illegal copy from happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, your call to `vector_init(vector, 3)` makes a *copy* of `vector` to pass to `vector_init`, but `vector` is uninitialized.  Since the program needs to read from `vector` in order to copy it, and reading from uninitialized variables results in undefined behavior, that program's behavior is undefined.

In contrast, in your second example nothing is ever read from an uninitialized variable.  Since `vector_init` takes its argument by reference, no copy needs to be made.  *Writing* to an uninitialized variable is well-defined, so the result is a well-defined program and well-defined values for the members of `vector`.

Comment: Thank you for this well written answer ☺️

Answer (score 2):

> I instead pass the Vector-struct as a reference, the error goes away.

The **warning** goes away because the uninitialized `Vector` isn't read. You only assign values to its members.

In the first example, the uninitialized `Vector` is copied (used/read), causing *undefined behavior*.